# Forming Committees

Tags: probability

The question is:

*A group of 12 students of which 4 are freshmen, 5 are sophomores, and 3 are juniors, need to form a committee consisting of 2 freshmen, 3 sophomores, and 2 juniors. How many different committees are possible?*

I`m not sure how to do this problem; do I just put the number of needed people over the available subjects? **eg. 2 freshman / 4 freshman** and then multiply them all together? Or is a combination/permutation problem? Any help on getting started or an explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: You got the right idea, except that you must use binomial coefficients instead of divisions.

Comment: It's a multiple-combination problem: how many ways to choose 2 freshmen out of 4, times how many ways to choose 3 sophomores out of 5, etc.

Comment: Don't do it. Committees always make bad decisions.

Comment: So in order to solve this, I must multiply 2 choose 4 by 3 choose 5, etc?

Comment: @ToxicTechnetium:  One would usually say 4 choose 2 and so on-the total number comes first.  But you are correct in your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the product of 3 (easy) combination problems. the answer is 
$$
\binom{4}{2}_\mbox{freshman} \times
\binom{5}{3}_\mbox{sophomore} \times
\binom{3}{2}_\mbox{junior} = 6\times 10 \times 3 = 180
$$